# creating table from array with different length and value php

Tags: php, html

```
Array
(
[25p] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 353
                [label] => C81
                [casting] => 21 Mar 2017
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 1
                                [y] => 6.220000
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 2
                                [y] => 10.220000
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 7
                                [y] => 21.440000
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 28
                                [y] => 30.780000
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 354
                [label] => C82
                [casting] => 21 Mar 2017
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 1
                                [y] => 8.000000
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 3
                                [y] => 20.890000
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 6
                                [y] => 30.670000
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 7
                                [y] => 32.555000
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 28
                                [y] => 51.110000
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 355
                [label] => C83
                [casting] => 21 Mar 2017
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 1
                                [y] => 7.110000
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 3
                                [y] => 19.780000
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 6
                                [y] => 23.560000
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 7
                                [y] => 32.225000
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [x] => 15
                                [y] => 38.890000
                            )

                    )

            )

        [age] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 6
                [4] => 7
                [5] => 15
                [6] => 28
            )

    )

)
```

i want to create a table based on the `[age]` value as the header. i managed to create the table but the problem is, my data is not placed correctly. the `[age]` is based on unique flatten list of the `[data][x]` value. From the array data, `C83` should not have data for 2D because no `[data][x] = 2`

```
+---------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
| Monitor Label |    1D    |    2D     |    3D     |    6D     |    7D     | 15D | 28D |
+---------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
| C81           | 6.220000 | 10.220000 | 21.440000 | 30.780000 |           |     
|     |
| C82           | 8.000000 | 20.890000 | 30.670000 | 32.555000 | 51.110000 |     
|     |
| C83           | 7.110000 | 19.780000 | 23.560000 | 32.225000 | 38.890000 |     
|     |
+---------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

below is my code to generate the table above

```
    //test creating HTML
foreach($graph as $grade => $data )
{
  echo '<strong>'.strtoupper($grade).'</strong></br>';
  //start the table for each grade
  echo '<table border=1>';
  echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Monitor Label</th>';

    for($i=0;$i < count($data['age']);$i++)
    {
      echo '<th>'.$data['age'][$i].'D</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  echo '</thead>';
  echo '<tbody>';

  for ($i=0;$i < count($data)-1; $i++)
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data[$i]['label'].'</td>';
    foreach($data[$i]['data'] as $x)
    {
      echo '<td>'.$x['y'].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }

  echo '</tbody>';
  echo '</table>';
}
```

some of the `[data][y]` should be missing and i want to replace it with - (dash) or #NA but it just fill the table column.

if anyone interested with the data, here is the actual serialize data

```
a:4:{s:3:"30n";a:2:{i:0;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:423;s:5:"label";s:3:"D43";s:7:"casting";s:11:"05 Apr 2017";s:4:"data";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:1;s:1:"y";s:8:"7.330000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:9:"13.560000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:3;s:1:"y";s:9:"16.890000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:7;s:1:"y";s:9:"38.000000";}i:4;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:27;s:1:"y";s:9:"32.670000";}}}s:3:"age";a:5:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:7;i:4;i:27;}}s:3:"30p";a:5:{i:0;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:428;s:5:"label";s:3:"D48";s:7:"casting";s:11:"05 Apr 2017";s:4:"data";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:1;s:1:"y";s:8:"8.000000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:9:"15.560000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:3;s:1:"y";s:9:"20.670000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:7;s:1:"y";s:9:"30.440000";}i:4;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:27;s:1:"y";s:9:"42.885000";}}}i:1;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:238;s:5:"label";s:3:"a70";s:7:"casting";s:11:"23 Jan 2017";s:4:"data";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:1;s:1:"y";s:8:"9.560000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:3;s:1:"y";s:9:"18.890000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:4;s:1:"y";s:9:"22.890000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:8;s:1:"y";s:9:"31.775000";}i:4;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:28;s:1:"y";s:9:"40.220000";}}}i:2;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:240;s:5:"label";s:3:"a72";s:7:"casting";s:11:"23 Jan 2017";s:4:"data";a:6:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:1;s:1:"y";s:8:"9.330000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:9:"16.000000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:3;s:1:"y";s:9:"21.560000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:8;s:1:"y";s:9:"34.890000";}i:4;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:28;s:1:"y";s:9:"46.000000";}i:5;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:31;s:1:"y";s:9:"52.220000";}}}i:3;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:235;s:5:"label";s:3:"a68";s:7:"casting";s:11:"21 Jan 2017";s:4:"data";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:8:"7.560000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:4;s:1:"y";s:9:"15.560000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:10;s:1:"y";s:9:"23.890000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:28;s:1:"y";s:9:"32.440000";}}}s:3:"age";a:10:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:7;i:5;i:8;i:6;i:10;i:7;i:27;i:8;i:28;i:9;i:31;}}s:3:"35p";a:5:{i:0;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:424;s:5:"label";s:3:"D44";s:7:"casting";s:11:"05 Apr 2017";s:4:"data";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:1;s:1:"y";s:8:"8.670000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:8:"9.560000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:3;s:1:"y";s:9:"18.440000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:7;s:1:"y";s:9:"33.110000";}i:4;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:27;s:1:"y";s:9:"40.335000";}}}i:1;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:425;s:5:"label";s:3:"D45";s:7:"casting";s:11:"05 Apr 2017";s:4:"data";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:1;s:1:"y";s:8:"8.890000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:9:"19.560000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:3;s:1:"y";s:9:"26.890000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:7;s:1:"y";s:9:"39.780000";}i:4;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:27;s:1:"y";s:9:"49.445000";}}}i:2;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:426;s:5:"label";s:3:"D46";s:7:"casting";s:11:"05 Apr 2017";s:4:"data";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:1;s:1:"y";s:8:"6.670000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:9:"16.440000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:3;s:1:"y";s:9:"16.440000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:7;s:1:"y";s:9:"26.670000";}i:4;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:29;s:1:"y";s:9:"40.670000";}}}i:3;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:269;s:5:"label";s:4:"NS23";s:7:"casting";s:11:"01 Feb 2017";s:4:"data";a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:1;s:1:"y";s:8:"6.670000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:5;s:1:"y";s:9:"21.780000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:7;s:1:"y";s:9:"26.000000";}}}s:3:"age";a:7:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:5;i:4;i:7;i:5;i:27;i:6;i:29;}}s:3:"45p";a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:233;s:5:"label";s:3:"A65";s:7:"casting";s:11:"21 Jan 2017";s:4:"data";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:9:"15.110000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:5;s:1:"y";s:9:"32.440000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:10;s:1:"y";s:9:"44.665000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:28;s:1:"y";s:9:"55.483333";}}}i:1;a:4:{s:2:"id";i:234;s:5:"label";s:3:"a66";s:7:"casting";s:11:"21 Jan 2017";s:4:"data";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:2;s:1:"y";s:9:"14.220000";}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:5;s:1:"y";s:9:"33.780000";}i:2;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:10;s:1:"y";s:9:"44.780000";}i:3;a:2:{s:1:"x";i:28;s:1:"y";s:9:"55.560000";}}}s:3:"age";a:4:{i:0;i:2;i:1;i:5;i:2;i:10;i:3;i:28;}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ask around and finally receive got an answer and solution for this.

[phpfreaks Forum](https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/304301-creating-table-from-array-with-different-value/)

basically, the array is re-arrange and simplified to get the [x] and [y] value. then [x] is added to its own array. later, loop through the data using [x] as the array key to get the [y] value.

i have since re-arrange my array to simplified this process and my array

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code where i loop over age and check with 'x' value in data

```
//test creating HTML
 foreach($graph as $grade => $data )

 echo '<strong>'.strtoupper($grade).'</strong></br>';
 //start the table for each grade
 echo '<table border=1>';
 echo '<thead>';
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<th>Monitor Label</th>';

 for($i=0;$i < count($data['age']);$i++)
 {
    echo '<th>'.$data['age'][$i].'D</th>';
 }
 echo '</tr>';
 echo '</thead>';
 echo '<tbody>';

 for ($i=0;$i < count($data)-1; $i++)
 {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data[$i]['label'].'</td>';
    for($j=0;$j < count($data['age']);$j++){
       foreach($data[$i]['data'] as $x)
       {
           if($x['x'] == $data['age'][$j])
             echo '<td>'.$x['y'].'</td>';
           else
             echo '<td> #NA </td>';
       }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }

  echo '</tbody>';
  echo '</table>';
 }
```

Comment: this fill the table with a lot of empty value

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop for `count($data['age']` iterations over all the `$data[$i]['data']` arrays, but each time check if an array with that occurance exists. If it does you print the `['y']` number and if not you print your `-` or `N/A` in the table column instead.

Replace

```
foreach($data[$i]['data'] as $x)
{
  echo '<td>'.$x['y'].'</td>';
}
```

which will only loop the number of times that a `['data']` occurance actually exists

With

```
for ($y=0; $y < count($data['age']; $y++) {
    if ( isset($data[$i]['data'][$y]) ) {
        if ( $data[$i]['data'][$y]['x'] == $data['age'][$i] ) {
            echo '<td>'.$data[$i]['data'][$y]['y'].'</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>N/A</td>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<td>N/A</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: it does print the `NA` but the data is still not placed correctly. the `NA` is added at the end of the table. maybe i need to re-format on how to display the data table

Comment: Ahhh, woops I missed that. Let me have another think